# How can I find kafka config file?

Tags: python, terminal, apache-kafka

I have an error using kafka `Error while executing topic command replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0` when I tried to create a topic.

And I found the solution ([Error creating Kafka Topics- Replication factor larger than available brokers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098366/error-creating-kafka-topics-replication-factor-larger-than-available-brokers)) by modifying config file

```
cp config/server.properties config/server-1.properties
cp config/server.properties config/server-2.properties)
```

But my problem is that I can't find the config file `cp: config/server.properties: No such file or directory`

Could someone help me how to find it using terminal on Mac?

Comment: what files do you have in the config directory? did you delete something?

Comment: Thanks for asking :) I just don't know where the config directory is located on mac.. Could you guide me?

Comment: how are you using kafka then?

Answer (score 22):

If you are using the docker image from confluent, e.g. `confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka`, they are located in `/etc/kafka`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use **locate kafka** command on MAC to search.

On my Mac the location of all configuration file is.

**/usr/local/etc/kafka/**

Answer (score 1):

If your are on Ubuntu 20 with Kafka 2.8.1, I found it's in `/usr/local/kafka/config`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hortonworks (now Cloudera) HDP, it is located in `/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/kafka/conf`