# Kafka topic is not creating

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I was installing kafka in Quickstart Cloudera VM using following  [link](http://%20https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/installing-apache-kafka-on-clouderas-quickstart-vm-8245d8d0ebe5)

but when i am running below command

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper quickstart.cloudera:2181 --create --topic test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

I am getting following error

```
19/09/21 11:28:36 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:2181, sessionid = 0x16d54d21037009d, negotiated timeout = 30000
19/09/21 11:28:38 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient: [ZooKeeperClient] Connected.
Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
19/09/21 11:28:40 ERROR admin.TopicCommand$: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
```

I tried to resolve this issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098366/error-creating-kafka-topics-replication-factor-larger-than-available-brokers). but when running below command

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

but getting error.

```
19/09/21 11:54:42 ERROR quorum.QuorumPeerMain: Invalid config, exiting abnormally
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing config/zookeeper.properties
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:131)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:106)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: config/zookeeper.properties file is missing
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:115)
... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

Any lead is appreciated.

Actually I want to connect kafka to spark. If there is another way to do it. that is also fine.

Comment: 1) `config/zookeeper.properties file is missing` ... What files are there in the config folder? 2) Seems like Kafka isn't running. How did you start it? 3) Do you really need a VM? Spark, Kafka, and Zookeeper all work outside of one

Comment: __cloudera_generation__,  __cloudera_metadata__, kafka-client.conf, tools-log4j.properties

Comment: above files are present. I installed it using parcels. So don't know why that file is not there. I need to work on HDFS, Spark, kafka. So I want to use this. I also tried to install kafka in my windows but getting same error.

Comment: You should have all these files in the config folder https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/config

Comment: How should i get these files there? Any suggestion?

Comment: Copy the github file text into a file in the VM?

Comment: I try installing Kafka in windows also. In there config folder all these files are there but it is giving me below error

Comment: Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
[2019-09-22 15:08:13,903] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

Comment: Are you running `kafka-server-start` also? As far as I can tell, you've only started Zookeeper

Answer (score 0):

> Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.

Your first error message says it all. It seems like you start only the zookeeper process, but not the broker. The error says that no brokers in the cluster.

Make sure that you start a Kafka broker with [important broker configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs), make sure the zookeeper is the one you started!.